# Script to Create multipath.conf Alias

Tags: awk, multipath-storage

I found a script to create alias for multipath  for Nimble volumes and I modified it to work in freenas
the content of it is

```
#/bin/bash
# This script will scan the system for attached Nimble Volumes
# and output a list of multipath alias statements for the linux
# /etc/multipath.conf.  This will allow for the volume to be 
# referenced by the volume name in place of the normal mpathX
# 
# To use the script, just run it.  If Nimble volumes are present
# it will output the confiugration data to standard out
# Just copy and paste that output in to /etc/multipath.conf
# Take care when adding these lines to make sure another alias
# is not present or if there are other multipath statements

# Start by checking to see if we have any Nimble volumes connected
ls -l /dev/disk/by-path | grep freenas > /dev/null

if [ $? -eq 0 ] 
then

#Build list of Nimble devices
DEV_LIST=$(ls -l /dev/disk/by-path | grep freenas | awk '{print $NF'} | sed 's/..\/..\///')

# Output the first line of the config
echo "multipaths {"

# For each device found we determine the name and the mpathid
for i in $DEV_LIST
    do

    SUBSTRING=$(ls -l /dev/disk/by-path | grep $i  | awk -F: '{print $4}') 

    # This uses pattern matching to find the name of the volume
    OFFSET=$(echo $SUBSTRING | awk --re-interval 'match($0, /\-[v][a-z0-9]{16}/) { print RSTART-1 }')
    NIMBLEVOL=${SUBSTRING::$OFFSET}

    # Here we collect the MPATHID
    MPATHID=$(multipath -ll /dev/$i | grep FreeBSD | awk '{print $2}' | sed -e 's\(\\g' | sed -e 's\)\\g')

    # Enable for debug
    #echo "Volume name for $device is $nimblevol with multipath ID is $mpathid"

    # Putting it all together with proper formatting using printf
    MULTIPATH=$(printf "multipath {\n \t\twwid \t\t%s \n \t\talias\t\t %s\n \t}" $MPATHID $NIMBLEVOL)
    MATCH='multipaths {'

    echo "$MULTIPATH"

    done

    # End the configuration section
    echo "}"
else 

    # If no Nimble devices found, exit with message
    echo "No Nimble Devices Found, have you met leeloo?"
    exit 1
fi

exit 0
```

when I run it it get

```
multipaths {
multipath {
                wwid            36589cfc000000e9f2e24f431339ec7b0
                alias
        }
multipath {
                wwid            36589cfc00000026c07d6caed9e43aa22
                alias
        }
multipath {
                wwid            36589cfc000000f051b0d5718e0b46b2f
                alias
        }
multipath {
                wwid            36589cfc000000af38b5be525e3cf1cb4
                alias
        }
multipath {
                wwid            36589cfc000000824684e211c61d58fc5
                alias
        }
multipath {
                wwid            36589cfc000000f0f579280a94ef72125
                alias
        }
multipath {
                wwid            36589cfc000000e9f2e24f431339ec7b0
                alias
        }
multipath {
                wwid            36589cfc00000026c07d6caed9e43aa22
                alias
        }
multipath {
                wwid            36589cfc000000f051b0d5718e0b46b2f
                alias
        }
multipath {
                wwid            36589cfc000000af38b5be525e3cf1cb4
                alias
        }
multipath {
                wwid            36589cfc000000824684e211c61d58fc5
                alias
        }
multipath {
                wwid            36589cfc000000f0f579280a94ef72125
                alias
        }
}
```

without any alias 
do you have any suggestions??

Comment: either SUBSTRING or OFFSET failed to initialize properly, besides  devices are listed twice.

Comment: SUBSTRING is fine as i get output but i think OFFSET is the problem so can you help me please

Comment: How does the `ls -l /dev/disk/by-path` output look like?

Comment: can you edit your post with a sample of SUBSTRING ?

Comment: SUBSTIRNGacsf-lun-0 -> ../../sdd
data1-lun-0 -> ../../sdm
data2-lun-0 -> ../../sdj
ocr1-lun-0 -> ../../sdf
ocr2-lun-0 -> ../../sdb
ocr3-lun-0 -> ../../sdh
acsf-lun-0 -> ../../sde
data1-lun-0 -> ../../sdk
data2-lun-0 -> ../../sdl
ocr1-lun-0 -> ../../sdg
ocr2-lun-0 -> ../../sdc
ocr3-lun-0 -> ../../sdi

Comment: ls -l /dev/disk/by-path
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Feb 27 15:26 ip-192.168.0.253:3260-iscsi-freenas:acsf-lun-0 -> ../../sdd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Feb 27 15:26 ip-192.168.0.253:3260-iscsi-freenas:data1-lun-0 -> ../../sdm
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Feb 27 15:26 ip-192.168.0.253:3260-iscsi-freenas:data2-lun-0 -> ../../sdj
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Feb 27 15:26 ip-192.168.0.253:3260-iscsi-freenas:ocr1-lun-0 -> ../../sdf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Feb 27 15:26 ip-192.168.0.253:3260-iscsi-freenas:ocr2-lun-0 -> ../../sdb
there is more but no chareachters left to paste the all output

Comment: I can share teamviewer ID if you want to check yourself

Comment: @Thomas You are amazing that's worked for me
but do you know how to remove the dublicate as i got this

multipaths {
multipath {
                wwid            36589cfc000000e9f2e24f431339ec7b0
                alias            acsf
        }
multipath {
                wwid            36589cfc00000026c07d6caed9e43aa22
                alias            data1
        }
multipath {
                wwid            36589cfc000000f051b0d5718e0b46b2f
                alias            data2
        }
multipath {
                wwid            36589cfc000000af38b5be525e3cf1cb4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment the lines starting with `OFFSET=` and `NIMBLEVOL=` and insert

```
NIMBLEVOL=$(echo $SUBSTRING | sed -e 's/^\(.*\)-lun.*/\1/')
```

right below the commented lines.

```
...
#OFFSET=$(echo $SUBSTRING | awk --re-interval 'match($0, /\-[v][a-z0-9]{16}/) { print RSTART-1 }')
#NIMBLEVOL=${SUBSTRING::$OFFSET}
NIMBLEVOL=$(echo $SUBSTRING | sed -e 's/^\(.*\)-lun.*/\1/')
...
```

Not sure if that will really will create a valid configuration, assuming you want to have data1, data2 etc as alias.

Comment: how to remove duplicates??

Comment: Might be not too easy without rewriting the complete script.Can you post the complete output of `ls -l /dev/disk/by-path`. But please use [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) to copy the output.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/2bNNJDJ2

Comment: I suggest to modify the for loop to count the half of the i entries if it possible??

Comment: Maybe for now it's best to edit the duplicates with a text editor and rewrite the script from scratch. Not really sure, the more I think about the script the more I suppose it's better to search for the volume names the other way round. `wwid -> /dev/sd* -> <volume-name>`

Comment: sorry but this script is not mine i modified it ..so if you can rewrite it for me i will appreciate it very much ..thanks in advance